# Paging vs. cursoring with max_id in TweetSharps ListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline

Tags: tweetsharp

In their 'Working with Timelines' document at http://dev.twitter.com/docs/working-with-timelines Twitter recommend cursoring using the `max_id` parameter in preference to attempting to step through a timeline page by page. Looking at the documentation for the Twitter API method `GET statuses/user_timeline` http://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline there is an optional `max_id` parameter, no `page` parameter, and other useful parameters like `include_rts` to include retweets. But the overloads for the TweetSharp method `ListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimeline` only include `page` and not `max_id`. Is it possible to retrieve a specified users timeline using the cursoring method (rather than paging) using TweetSharp and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It's included in TweetSharp as a separate method: `IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> ListTweetsOnSpecifiedUserTimelineBefore(string screenName, long maxId);`